# With sidekiq on heroku, is using REDIS_URL the same as defining the configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I have a Rails 4.2 app.  According to [sidekiq wiki on redis](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis), you do:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/12' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/12' }
end
```

to configure REDIS location.

But if I define `REDIS_URL` on heroku without doing the above, everything works just fine.  Are both REDIS_URL and the configuration above equivalent?  A quick glance at sidekiq source shows:

```
  def determine_redis_provider
    ENV[ENV['REDIS_PROVIDER'] || 'REDIS_URL']
  end
```

so it seems like they would be.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the [documentation,](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis) you can use any of those two alternatives as long as your ENV variable is named `REDIS_PROVIDER` and it's value is the name of the ENV variable which contains the Redis URL.

E.g: `REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL`

Either way, I would suggest you to use `config.redis` as it allows you to configure extra settings like `network_timeout`, which is an important setting in cloud-based systems like Heroku where timeouts are not the exception.